# nesting a try and catch in loop

Tags: java, for-loop, try-catch

We have a practical test on Java about an IceCream shop. We need to handle exceptions in case no more stock. The code from the app below works fine. Exceptions are properly managed.

```
public class IceCreamApp2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Prijslijst priceList2 = new Prijslijst(2, 5, 8);

        Stock stock = new Stock(1, 8, 2, 1);

        IceCreamCar iceCar = new IceCreamCar(priceList2, stock);


        try {
            Eatable[] eatCar = {
                    iceCar.orderCone(new Cone.Flavor[]{Cone.Flavor.CHOCOLATE, Cone.Flavor.BANANA, Cone.Flavor.VANILLA}),
                    iceCar.orderCone(new Cone.Flavor[]{Cone.Flavor.VANILLA, Cone.Flavor.VANILLA}),
                    iceCar.orderMagnum(Magnum.MagnumType.ROMANTICSTRAWBERRIES),
                    iceCar.orderMagnum(Magnum.MagnumType.ALPINENUTS),
                    iceCar.orderIceRocket()
            };
            for (int i = 0; i < eatCar.length; i++) {
                eatCar[i].eat();
            }
            System.out.println(iceCar.getProfit());
        } catch (NoMoreIceCreamException noMoreIce) {
            System.out.println("No More Ice To sell... Beat it!!");
            System.out.println("Message: " + noMoreIce.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Cause: " + noMoreIce.getCause());
        }
        System.out.println(iceCar.getProfit());
    }
}
```

However this logic is flawded, since it stops counting the rest of order when an exception appears. Therefore Magnums and Icerockets, despite they 're in stock, are not counted in profit.
To do this, we know we need to loop through the table "Eatable". But it doesn't work and exit code 1 with the exception:

```
public class IceCreamApp2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Prijslijst priceList2 = new Prijslijst(2, 5, 8);

        Stock stock = new Stock(1, 8, 2, 1);

        IceCreamCar iceCar = new IceCreamCar(priceList2, stock);

        Eatable[] eatCar = {
                iceCar.orderCone(new Cone.Flavor[]{Cone.Flavor.CHOCOLATE, Cone.Flavor.BANANA, Cone.Flavor.VANILLA}),
                iceCar.orderCone(new Cone.Flavor[]{Cone.Flavor.VANILLA, Cone.Flavor.VANILLA}),
                iceCar.orderMagnum(Magnum.MagnumType.ROMANTICSTRAWBERRIES),
                iceCar.orderMagnum(Magnum.MagnumType.ALPINENUTS),
                iceCar.orderIceRocket()
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < eatCar.length; i++) {
            try {
                eatCar[i].eat();
            } catch (NoMoreIceCreamException noMoreIce) {
                System.out.println("No More Ice To sell... Beat it!!");
                System.out.println("Message: " + noMoreIce.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Cause: " + noMoreIce.getCause());
            }

        }
        System.out.println(iceCar.getProfit());
    }
}
```

Any clue what can be wrong ?

Comment: What's wrong with your second snippet?

Comment: Does `eat` throw some other exception apart from NoMoreIceCreamException?

Comment: in the top snippet, you could declare ```int i = 0``` prior to the try/catch. That way, it is visible to both parts. By declaring it inside of the ```for``` loop, you've limited the scope of ```i``` to the inside of the loop block. I would personally go the route you've gone in the second snippet. Can you update this post with the stack trace so we can see why that isn't working? It seems that it should be from this code snippet.

Comment: Check if the item is in stock before allowing it be ordered and there will never be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the stack trace :

```
Preparing your Balls on a cone
Exception in thread "main" Seller.NoMoreIceCreamException: No more Balls or Cones
    at Seller.IceCreamCar.prepareCone(IceCreamCar.java:39)
    at Seller.IceCreamCar.orderCone(IceCreamCar.java:30)
    at App.IceCreamApp2.main(IceCreamApp2.java:18)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

@Andrew S the condition is already handled in the class “IceCreamCar”. In short:

```
public class IceCreamCar implements IceCreamSeller {

    // Instance Variables
    Prijslijst priceList;
    Stock stock;
    private double profit;


    // Constructor
    public IceCreamCar() {

    }

    public IceCreamCar(Prijslijst priceList, Stock stock) {
        this.priceList = priceList;
        this.stock = stock;
    }


    // Methods
    // Order Cone
    @Override
    public Cone orderCone(Cone.Flavor[] balls) {
        this.prepareCone(balls);
        return new Cone(balls);
    }

//    // Prepare Cone
    private Cone prepareCone(Cone.Flavor[] balls) {
        int countCones = 1;

        if (stock.getCones() < 0 || stock.getBalls() < 0) {
            throw new NoMoreIceCreamException("No more Balls or Cones");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
                stock.setBalls(stock.getBalls() - balls.length);
                profit += priceList.getBallPrice();
            }
            System.out.println("Preparing your Balls on a cone");
            countCones++;
            stock.setCones(stock.getCones() - countCones);
        }
        return new Cone(balls);
    }
```

thanks to both of you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so problem solved. Actually the solution is to put the try and catch in each of the orderCone, orderMagnum, etc...
That was exceptions are handled properly.